# JS access an array with in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a variable holding a string of validated JSON. The JSON is a set of strings each with a value of an array. I'd like to access the string and each array value.

```
var json_string = {"div-1":["div-1A", "div-1B"], "div-2":["div-2A", "div-2B"]};

//Run some code to get the following result:
console.log("div-1" has "div-1A");
console.log("div-1" has "div-1B");
console.log("div-2" has "div-2A");
console.log("div-2" has "div-2B");
```

I have tried a bunch of different things but nothing seems to work right. Additionally, I get a weird functionality. If I do the following:

```
console.log(json_string["div-1"]);
```

I randomly get the following results for each page refresh :

```
div-1A //initial load
div-1C //refresh 1
div-1A //refresh 2
div-1B //etc
div-1A //etc
```

Any ideas how I can get what I am after?

Comment: What is `console.log("div-1" has "div-1A");`? Have you tried `indexOf()`?

Comment: Which is it? An object or a JSON string?

Comment: How are you getting your JSON string?  It's possible you're getting different values because you're loading or assigning different values

Comment: @BotNet It is not a properly formatted JS object so I have it has a JSON formatted string. I do a JSON stringify and then JSON parse before running the above.

Comment: I don't understand.  How is it not properly formatted?  Literal JSON (as a string) is much more strict than JavaScript.  And, it's not JSON if what you're showing above is not a string.  You are displaying a JavaScript object.  A string is encapsulated in single or double quotes, unless that isn't JavaScript; for example, `'{ "text": ["array element"]}'` -- single quotes around it make it a string.  There's no reason to stringify a string.  You have to stringify because it's an object.  Anyhow, see answer below

Comment: Why would you do a `JSON.stringify` and then a `JSON.parse`? You will end up with exactly what you started with.

Comment: I was just taking shots in the dark. I have it figured out now. I can use the var with the string as is and it works thanks to the answers below.

Comment: @KeithC. please re-read the comment above -- it's not a string!  It's important you understand that concept.

Comment: @BotNet Yup, totally get it. It's not a string because I have it in proper JS object format. It would be a string if say it were wrapped in single quotes. In which case it could be JSON that needed to be converted to an object for example. Totally get it though and everything works today. TY!

Comment: @KeithC. good :) and to be proper JSON, it would need to follow a specific format (double quotes, etc), which JavaScript is more forgiving.  People think JSON is JavaScript, but it isn't.  It's just highly influenced by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first retrieve the values from keys and then use `forEach`  to get their value

```
var json_string = {"div-1":["div-1A", "div-1B"], 
                  "div-2":["div-2A", "div-2B"]
                  };
for(var key in json_string){
 var _getValue = json_string[key]
 if(_getValue.constructor===Array){  // Checking if it is an array
       _getValue.forEach(function(item){

      document.write('<pre>'+item+'</pre>')
     })
     }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/15p0m2wb/)

Comment: Not me, but I don't have enough rep to up vote yet. I will when I can.

Comment: Thanks you Sir ! not an issue

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** for getting all object keys and **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** for iterating over array.

```js
var json_string = {
  "div-1": ["div-1A", "div-1B"],
  "div-2": ["div-2A", "div-2B"]
};

// Get all object keys and iterate over them
Object.keys(json_string).forEach(function(key) {
  // Get inner array using key and iterate
  json_string[key].forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(key + ' has ' + el)
  });
});
```

---

For older browser check polyfill option for [Object.keys method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) and [forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).

Comment: Thank you, this also works. Note I read elsewhere that object.keys is not support by IE8 and older for anyone else reading this.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be something like this if I understand correctly. You have to traverse through each property and take the array property value against that key.

```
for (key in json_string) {
    var arr = json_string[key];
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(key + ' has ' + item);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't seem to work. The result in console log was again random results such as div-1 has div-1C, div-1 has div-1A, div-1 has div-1B, div-1 has div-1A.

Comment: Disregard above comment, there was data collision breaking something in my working code set. This works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your *json_string* is actually a JSON object (there's a difference).  That said, keys within an object do not follow any sort/ordering.  You will need to sort your keys before your output:

```js
var obj = {
  "div-1": ["div-1A", "div-1B"],
  "div-2": ["div-2A", "div-2B"]
};

Object.keys( obj ).sort().forEach( key =>
  obj[ key ].sort().forEach( val =>
    console.log( [key,'has',val].join(' ') )
  )
);
```

Of course you could also write your own function to output values for a specific key.  Below adds a prototype function to Object, which is just an example (prototyping is generally not recommended):

```js
Object.prototype.valuesFor = function(key){
  this[key].sort().forEach( val => 
    console.log( [key,'has',val].join(' ') )
  )
  return this[key];
};

var obj = {
  "div-1": ["div-1A", "div-1B"],
  "div-2": ["div-2A", "div-2B"]
};

obj.valuesFor('div-1')
```

Comment: I love how people leave negative points, without issuing comments.